# sudo certbot delete created errors

Tags: nginx, ssl, certbot

I wanted to delete my Certbot SSL, I ran "sudo certbot delete" and did it. After when restarting nginx, it gave me this error:

> nginx: [emerg] cannot load certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/fishymine.xyz/fullchain.pem": BIO_new_file() failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen('/etc/letsencrypt/live/fishymine.xyz/fullchain.pem','r') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file).

How do I fix this?

Comment: What did you expect? You deleted the certificate. Now Nginx is reporting an error that it cannot open the certificate file.

Comment: Yes I know, but shouldn't it make it like when I started nginx for the first time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that certbot automatically insert config rules when you add a certificate. All of the inserted lines includes "***Cerbot***" so you can do this to remove these lines :

```
sudo sed -i '/Certbot/d' /etc/nginx/sites-available/*
sudo sed -i '/Certbot/d' /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*
```

then try

```
sudo nginx -t
sudo certbot --nginx
```

if you still get an error, you can check the files in `/etc/nginx/sites-*` manually, or just delete their content if you don't care about the existing config by :

```
sudo chmod 777 /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
sudo echo '' > /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
sudo chmod 644 /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

sudo chmod 777 /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
sudo echo '' > /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
sudo chmod 644 /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
```